# Made up UUIDs like 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Tags: uuid

I'm writing an application that uses UUIDs to identify datasets. There is no import of foreign UUIDs, all UUIDs are generated by the app.
There is a default dataset that I like to recognize easily as a human being.

As 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 is equal likely as any other generated UUID, would you say it's ok to manually chose that as the UUID for my default dataset?

Or even consecutive ranges of UUIDs for some chosen datasets?

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want some easily recognizable UUIDs for specific datasets? If so I'd like to know your use case.

Comment: It aids in debugging. E.g. in group memberships you can spot that value easily in a list of hundreds of values

Comment: To fidle around with UUIDs like this to make debugging easier seems like a bad idea to me. At least in code. You could set up a test evironment with certain for debugging but don't change your productive code for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must never manually generate UUIDs: rely on the OS to do this for you.

By the way, 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 is reserved by the component object model.